# rails application to download youtube video

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I create a rails application that will have code to download the video from youtube ?

Is there any API that can be used or any gem available in rails.

Thanks,
gsoni

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Youtube-dl](http://rg3.github.com/youtube-dl/) and call that from Rails.

Comment: Hi,
I tried it ,but firstly it download the whole video on the server and then we need to render that file to download to the user.And in that case if we have this application on heroku then it will give us timeout error etc.
What i want that we need not to save that file first on our server(I am doing this in tmp folder), and directly render the content to user which is going to be downloaded by this "youtube-dl"

Answer (score 1):

Create scaffold for storing url and result:

```
link:string
data:text
```

You need store hash inside "data", so in your model:

```
  serialize :data, Hash
```

Install wrapper for this lib

```
gem 'youtube-dl.rb'
```

In your controller after saving link from your form

```
  @hash = YoutubeDL.get "#{@link.link}", {skip_download: true}
  @link.data = @hash.information
  @link.save!
```

After that you can get some keys from your data hash. For example:

```
@link.data[:title]
```

Comment: Try to use some forks from youtube-dl.rb. This gem not supported I think.